# Java Script Online survey with mulitple pages

Tags: javascript

I am creating online experiment. My experiment has four conditions and participants are required to complete all four studies.
But, the problem is that I need to create four separate pages for four conditions, and I need to save all responses from each page to the data storage. 
I was originally using

```
<input type="button" value="Continue" onclick="parent.location='page2.html'">
```

but none of the information from page 1 is saved. Could you please help me?
The bottom line, when participants click the next button, their responses will be sent to the data storage and take them to the next page as well. (two functions).

Comment: Sounds like a job for [`window.sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage).

Comment: You can store data from webpages using [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage#localStorage) or using [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie) which are more widely supported by allow lower volume of data typically

Comment: Wow, I thought you'd get a decent answer by now. Is this still a problem? How do you send the actual survey results to the server?